# Android .aar library interface paramether name lost

Tags: java, android, interface, aar

I use Android Studio (1.2.2). I built a Android module library which has a interface declared:

```
public interface myInterface {
    void onSuccess(String returnedId);

    void onFailure(Exception e);
}
```

I compile the project and I get the .aar file from **build/outputs/aar/** directory. Then I import the .aar to a project with **Import .JAR or .AAR package**. I set it as a module dependency and import the interface to a class where I want tot use it.

The problem is that when I want to use the imported interface the autocomplete does not complete the interface variables with the descriptive name I set when building the library. Goint to the declaration on the interface in the imported .aar file, I find this:

```
public interface myInterface {
       void onSuccess(String var1);

       void onFailure(Exception var1);
 }
```

What I want:

> void onSuccess(String returnedId);

What I get:

> public void onSuccess(String s) {

Comment: Are the library and the app inside the same project?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @larsgrefer. The library is imported as a .aar file. It's set as a module dependency. The path to the .aar file is inside the current project.

Comment: Please add the `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files of your app and your library

Answer (score 0):

The `.aar` file only contains the compiled code (`.class` files inside a `.jar` file)

If you want to see the real parameter names in *Android Studio*, you have to tell *Android Studio* where it can find the source code (the `*.java` files) of your library.

Comment: It would be useful if you have included the steps to tell the Android Studio where it can find the source code (the *.java files) of library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the situation in which the working Android module library was changed and these changes were not noted by the calling App.

```
- Save all files in the App
- Quit Android Studio (not close, really quit/force stop)
- Open Android Studio again
- Load the App (if not done automatically)
- Project Clear
```

For me this solved it.